# Amazon Web Service, Missing Storage Volume

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I am having a problem here in AWS Instance I already created the volume but when I check in the Remote Desktop it only shows the 100GB storage.

Check this Image for reference,

[Volume Storage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1Qg7e.png)

Comment: yes still unclear

Answer (score 0):

Attaching new volume to an instance is not enough to be able to use it. You have to **format it** for your operating system. For example, for linux:

- [Make an Amazon EBS volume available for use on Linux](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ebs-using-volumes.html)

Comment: I am using Windows 2016 Center

Comment: @ChristianBalagtas Your question does not even mention Windows 2016 Center.